# How to create array with hours in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, time, hash

I need to create the following Array:

```
array_time = [00:00:00, 00:00:01, ..., 23:59:59]
```

Is there a way to generate this type of hash with all hours of the day in ruby?

Because then I will need to create the following Hash:

```
hash = { "time" => { "'00:00:00'" => "23:59:59" } }
```

And I would like to check if the sub-Hash under key `"time"` uses keys in the correct format, for example:

```
hash["time"].each do |key|
  array_time.includes key
end
```

Comment: You say "hash" but then your first example is an array. So which is it?

Comment: You say "all hours" but your first example shows "all seconds". So which is it?

Comment: Sorry, I switched to array

Comment: Is this all to accomplish a format check? Is that the ultimate goal? So like some RegEx or similar would get the job done? Or is there another reason you want an array of all possible HH:MM:SS of the day?

Comment: "I need to create the following Array" – Your desired result is not valid Ruby, so this is impossible.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you're happy with Strings, this is a simple way to do it:

```
array_time = ("00".."23").flat_map do |h|
  ("00".."59").flat_map do |m|
    ("00".."59").map do |s|
      "#{h}:#{m}:#{s}"
    end
  end
end

array_time.length
# => 86400

array_time.first(5)
# => ["00:00:00", "00:00:01", "00:00:02", "00:00:03", "00:00:04"]

array_time.last(5)
#=> ["23:59:55", "23:59:56", "23:59:57", "23:59:58", "23:59:59"]
```

However, if your goal is:

> and I would like to check if the hash time is in the correct format, example:
>
> ```
> hash["time"].each do |key|
>   array_time.include? key
> end
> ```

Then that's really not the most efficient way to go about it.

First off, Hash lookups are much faster than `Array#include?`, so you really want to use a Hash and treat it a Set:

```
time_set = Hash[
  ("00".."23").flat_map do |h|
    ("00".."59").flat_map do |m|
      ("00".."59").map do |s|
        ["#{h}:#{m}:#{s}", true]
      end
    end
  end
]

time_set
# => {"00:00:00"=>true,
#  "00:00:01"=>true,
#  "00:00:02"=>true,
#  ...
#  "23:59:58"=>true,
#  "23:59:59"=>true}
```

And then perform your lookups like this:

```
hash[:time].each do |time_str|
  time_set[time_str]
end
```

But even this is not great. Not always at least.

If you know you need to perform this check very often, with arbitrary values, and with a lot of values to check, then yes, pre-computing the lookup set *once* and storing it in a constant could make sense. So you'd use `TIME_SET = ...` instead of `time_set = ...`.

But if this is performed sporadically, you're just much better off validating the time strings one by one. For example:

```
TIME_REGEX = %r{^([01][0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]$}.freeze

hash[:time].each do |time_str|
  TIME_REGEX === time_str
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming an array of strings is acceptable, here is one way to do it.

```
time_iterator = Time.at(1_500_076_800) # 2017-07-15 00:00:00 +0000
end_time      = time_iterator + 1.day
array_time    = []
while time_iterator < end_time
  array_time << time_iterator.strftime('%T')
  time_iterator += 1.second
end
```

Apparently in Ruby 1.9 they removed the ability to step-iterate over a time range, so a while loop seems to be preferred now.

I do think that if you're just trying to validate the format of a time-like string (HH:MM:SS) then there are much better ways to accomplish this. A simple RegEx would do it, or something similar.